# SELECT COUNT DISTINCT for Child accounts

Tags: sql, select, distinct

Trying to get a count of sub accounts tied to the parent account via the Parent Number.

AccountName     AccountNum     ParentNum

---

```
Alpha          1000           NULL
Beta           2000           NULL
Gamma          3000           NULL
Gamma-Child1   4000           3000
Zeta           5000           NULL
Alpha-Child1   6000           1000
Alpha-Child2   7000           1000
Zeta-Child1    8000           5000
Alpha-Child3   9000           1000
```

My Attempt produces output but it looks off

```
SELECT AccountName, COUNT(DISTINCT ParentNum) AS "Count"
from Accounts
where ParentNum is not null
Group by Name
Order by Count desc
```

I'm getting counts but when validating against my data base the results are off.

Comment: Remove AccountName from the SELECT as it makes no sense in relation to retrieving the  overall parent count, Remove DISTINCT and remove the entire WHERE clause.

Comment: What is the exact output you expect here?

Answer (score 0):

The question does not require recursion which would actually make a solution easier. One way to solve this would be to break the parent and children up, counting each parent's child, and cheat a union back on the children with a count of zero :/ This requires 3 passes over the data which is not ideal. There could possibly a way to do this with 2 passes instead of 3.

```
SELECT T1.AccountName,T1.AccountNum,        
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY T2.ParentNum) AS ChildCount
FROM 
    Accounts T1
    INNER JOIN Accounts T2 ON T2.ParentNum = t1.AccountNum

UNION
    
SELECT AccountName,AccountNum, 0
FROM Accounts
WHERE NOT ParentNum IS NULL
```